# Rank of a node in BST using in-order traversal in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have been chasing my tail to find the rank of the node in a BST. I`ve got void function which accepts an element and using recursion finds a rank of the node.
I inserted nodes in the following order: **12, 3, 7, 4, 11, 17, 15, 9**.  My problem is that whenever I found a match the recursion does not stop! Here is my algorithm:

```
template <class Comparable>
void AugmentedBinarySearchTree<Comparable>::
Rank(const Comparable & x, BinaryNode<Comparable> *t, int *nodesVisited) const
{  

    // x is the element I am looking for
    // t is the root
    if (t->left != NULL)
    {

    Rank(x, t->left, nodesVisited);                         
    if(t->left->element == x)
        return; 
    }
    cout << "element " << t->element << ", x " << x << ", nodesVisited "<< *nodesVisited << endl;
    if (x == t->element) 
    {               

        cout << "found the node " << endl;
        return ; // exiting the recursion, nodesVisited will be the rank 
                // nodesVisited starts counting from 1
    }

    ++(*nodesVisited); // incrementing the count

    if (t->right != NULL)
    {       
        Rank(x, t->right, nodesVisited);    
    }
}
```

It works when I do Rank(3), but when I do Rank(4) recursion does not stop and I am getting different result:

```
element 3, x 4, nodesVisited 1
element 4, x 4, nodesVisited 2
found the node 
element 12, x 4, nodesVisited 2
element 15, x 4, nodesVisited 3
element 17, x 4, nodesVisited 4
RANK: 5
```

How do I stop the recursion whenever I found a match?

Answer (score 1):

You terminate the recursion if you found the item in the left child node.
 You need to stop if it was found in the left *subtree*.

Something like this might do it (I amended it to return the rank, as you said you intend to).
In my opinion, using a "null" base case often leads to simpler tree recursions.
(Thoroughly untested code, by the way. There are probably bugs.)

```
int Rank(const Comparable & x, const BinaryNode<Comparable> *t) const
{
    int rank = 0;
    return FindRank(x, t, &rank) ? rank : -1;
}

// Returns 'true' if and only if the node was found in 't'.
bool FindRank(const Comparable & x, const BinaryNode<Comparable> *t, int* nodesVisited) const
{
    if (t == nullptr)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (FindRank(x, t->left, nodesVisited))
    {
        return true;
    }

    *nodesVisited += 1;
    return t->element == x || FindRank(x, t->right, nodesVisited);
}
```

Comment: it should be a void function.

Comment: @inson Why does your code say "should return the rank", then? Changing `Rank` above to take a pointer parameter and not return anything is trivial.

Comment: I meant whenever the match is found, recursion should stop, and nodesVisited will "return" or gives us how many nodes we visited before hitting the match. If we don`t find a match it keep incrementing until it reaches the rightmost child.  It is not returning anything, it just stops. Sorry for confusion.